# The uploaded picture doesn't save to the database

Tags: javascript, php

I have been working on allowing the users to upload a profile picture. The picture shows when you choose it, but when you press the save button, it dissappears and isn't uploaded to the database.

This is the php code

```
if (!empty($_FILES) && isset($_POST['addPicture'])) {
    $file = $currentUser['userID'];

    $imageType = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["profile_picture"]["name"]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFile = "upload/profilePics/" . $file . "." . $imageType;

    try {
        if ($imageType != "jpg" && $imageType != "png" && $imageType != "jpeg" && $imageType != "gif") {
            throw new Exception('Dit is geen afbeelding');
        }

        $profileImage = "upload/profilePics/".$currentUser['userID'].".".$imageType;

        try{
            $user2 = new User();
            $user2->setEmail($_SESSION['user']);
            $user2->setProfileImage($profileImage);
            if ($user2->changePicture()){
                $currentUser= $user->getProfile();
                $feedback2 = "Saved";
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error2 = $e->getMessage();
        }


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error2 = $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

This is the function

```
public function changePicture(){
    $conn = Db::getInstance();

    $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET profileImage = :profileImage WHERE email = :email");
    $update->bindValue(':profileImage', $this->profileImage);
    $update->bindValue(':email', $this->email);
    return $update->execute();
}
```

This is the html code

```
<form class="addPic" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="imageContainer profilePic" style="background: url('<?php echo $currentUser["profileImage"] ?>') center;background-size: cover;"></div>
        <label for="profile_picture"></label>
        <input type="file" name="profile_picture" id="profile_picture" onchange="readURL(this);" class="form-control">

        <input name="addPicture" class="editPic" type="submit" value="Aanpassen">


    </form>
```

At last, this is the javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.profilePic').attr('style', "background: url('"+e.target.result+"') center;background-size: cover;");
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing in your exposed PHP code shows any attempts to upload to the database.  I'm suspecting it's within this call: `$user2->setProfileImage($profileImage);`  You might want to share that `User` class code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your datatype for the image field is set to BLOB.BLOBs are "Binary Large Objects" and are used to store large amounts of binary data, such as images or other types of files.

It is not a good practice of saving image in the database.
save image in some folder and save the path in the database.